# Optimizing this copy and paste process

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy and paste all non blank cells from one sheet to another sheet. At the moment I have managed to come up with this code to do it.

```
For i = 17 To 29

'CBCC'

    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("B" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("B" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("B" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("C" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("C" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("C" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("D" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("D" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("D" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("E" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("E" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("E" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("F" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("F" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("F" & i)

'ECAC'

    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("I" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("H" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("I" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("J" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("I" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("J" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("K" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("J" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("K" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("L" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("K" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("L" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("M" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("L" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("M" & i)

'Impairment'

    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("P" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("N" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("P" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("Q" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("O" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("Q" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("R" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("P" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("R" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("S" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("Q" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("S" & i)
     If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("T" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("R" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("T" & i)

'Total'

    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("V" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("T" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("V" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("W" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("U" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("W" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("X" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("V" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("X" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("Y" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("W" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("Y" & i)
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("Z" & i)) Then _
        Worksheets("Trends").Range("X" & i - 10) = Worksheets("Trends (N)").Range("Z" & i)

'End Import'

Next i
```

This is obviously not very efficient and if I ever needed to do it with a larger set of data it will take a very long time.

I have tried a few other ways of doing it but they don't seem to produce the results I need.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am quite a rookie at VBA at the moment.

Comment: You could read the data into an array --- Do processing on the array, read processed data into out_Array on the fly --- clear sheet --- read data in out_Array back into your sheet

Comment: What I have is a background sheet that does the raw data counts and then I want to move and only show the user the non empty cells. Then update the graphs that pull from this information.

Comment: If you want all (every cell) you could do something like `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value` which would set all of the cells in Sheet2 equal to the value of the cells in Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws(1) As Worksheet
Set ws(0) = Worksheets("Trends (N)") 'sheet you export from
Set ws(1) = Worksheets("Trends") 'sheet you export to
For i = 17 To 29

'CBCC'
For j = 2 To 6 'B to F
If Not IsEmpty(ws(0).Cells(i, j)) Then _
    ws(1).Cells(i - 10, j).Value2 = ws(0).Cells(i, j).Value2
Next j

'ECAC'
For j = 9 To 13 'I to M
If Not IsEmpty(ws(0).Cells(i, j)) Then _
    ws(1).Cells(i - 10, j - 1).Value2 = ws(0).Cells(i, j).Value2
Next j

'Impairment'
For j = 16 To 20 'P to T
If Not IsEmpty(ws(0).Cells(i, j)) Then _
    ws(1).Cells(i - 10, j - 2).Value2 = ws(0).Cells(i, j).Value2
Next j

'Total'
For j = 22 To 26 'V to Z
If Not IsEmpty(ws(0).Cells(i, j)) Then _
    ws(1).Cells(i - 10, j - 2).Value2 = ws(0).Cells(i, j).Value2
Next j

'End Import'

Next i
```